# gridview deletion issue. Can't delete a SQL record from the gridview delete button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

As much as I try to understand the delete methods of the gridview, I still can't figure how to delete a row. I'm using the same gridview to display 4 SQL tables. Depending on which table is selected, I go in a swich case to change the SELECT and DELETE command of the SQLDataSource. I'm not sure if this is the best practice but the SELECT portion works.

It is the deletion part that I need some help.

1. Is my thought process right on how to achieve my goal?
2. I have to have OnRowDeleting="gv1_RowDeleting" or else it gave me an
   error. Is this mandatory.
3. What is it with my code that doesn't work?

.ASPX :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="listTitle"><% Response.Write(strListTitle); %>
                <asp:GridView ID="gv1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    DataKeyNames="id" 
                    CellPadding="2" 
                    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
                    OnRowDeleting="gv1_RowDeleting"
                    OnRowDeleted="gv1_deleteItem">
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  <!-- close middle -->
    <div id="footer">

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>">
            <DeleteParameters> <asp:Parameter Name="id"/> </DeleteParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
```

.CS file:

```
   switch (strType)
    {
        case "servers":
            DS.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbServers";
            DS.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM tbServers WHERE id = @id";
            strListTitle = "Server List";
            break;
        case "systems":
            DS.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbSystems";
            DS.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM tbSystems WHERE id = @id";
            strListTitle = "System List";
            break;
        case "itOwners":
            DS.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbITowners";
            DS.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM tbITowners WHERE id = @id";
            strListTitle = "IT Owner List";
            break;
        case "systemOwners":
            DS.SelectCommand = "SELECT tbSystemOwners.id, tbITowners.owner, tbSystems.Systems FROM tbITowners INNER JOIN tbSystemOwners ON tbITowners.id = tbSystemOwners.idITowners INNER JOIN tbSystems ON tbSystemOwners.idSytems = tbSystems.id";
            DS.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM tbSystemOwners WHERE id = @id";
            strListTitle = "System Owner List";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    gv1.DataSource = DS;
    gv1.DataBind();
}

protected void gv1_deleteItem(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Display whether the delete operation succeeded.
    if (e.Exception == null)
    {
       Response.Write( "Row deleted successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
       Response.Write("An error occurred while attempting to delete the row.");
       e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}

 protected void gv1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: #2 Yes.................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re: #3
<s>I think the issue is that you are using the Parameter class as a delete parameter. The parameter class is a base class that doesn't contain the information you want - it's not going to pick up the ID from the row the delete button was clicked in, that's not going to get passed to the delete command, and I'd assume you get an SQL exception. (Or maybe you get a different error, because it's trying to pass along both id parameters, and can't find a function that accepts two. Haven't investigated)</s>

If you remove the delete parameters, the fact that you have id set as a DataKeyName means it should get passed along to your delete command automatically.

Above information is incorrect. Using a delete parameter in addition to a DataKeyName with autogenerated delete buttons doesn't seem to cause any issue.

The actual problem was using DataSource to associate the GridView with the SQLDataSource, instead of DataSourceID. DataSource doesn't persist on postback, whereas DataSourceID does. I'm not entirely sure what's going on under the hood, but the DataSource getting thrown out during the page life cycle screws up the Delete method call, so it never happens.

Long story short, use the DataSourceID property when using a control as your data source, and the DataSource property when using an object (e.g: a DataTable) as your data ource.

Comment: I've removed the line and I get the same thing.

Comment: Is it giving you an error, an SQL exception, or what? My guess is that DataKeyNames doesn't play nice with AutoGenerateColumns (which is defaulting to true), but it's hard to say.

Comment: Tried both ways also removed the DataKeyName and added the delete parameter. Same result

Comment: In gv1_deleteItem, what is e.Exception?

Comment: With your last question, it seems that the function gv1_deleteItem is not being called. Won't reach the breakpoint added.

Comment: I'm pretty stumped. I basically used the code snippets you provided, modified slightly to use another database, and it worked. Is your data source just `<asp:sqldatasource id="DS" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>" />` ? Is the datasource inside a form tag? In the snippet you provided above, it isn't.

Comment: From experimenting, try replacing `gv1.DataSource = DS;` with `gv1.DataSourceID = DS.ID;` .

Comment: Yes this the SQLDatasource is just that line and I move the DS in the form. doesn't change anything. I still can't get inside the gv1_deleteItem function.

Comment: DataBind() don't like the ID. What can prevent the process to not reach the OnRowDeleted="gv1_deleteItem" function?

Comment: What's the error it's giving you? Databind should be happy as long as you have only one of DataSourceID or DataSource set.

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'id'.

Comment: make sure you are using `gv1.DataSourceID = DS.ID;` and not `gv1.DataSource = DS.ID;`

Comment: .ID now works. Same result. Doesn't delete the record.